# Is wrapping an "Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Object>" in a try / catch(ClassCastException) enough to avoid run-time problems?

Tags: java, generics, casting, unchecked

I am writing a recursive converter for a `Map<String, Object>` (meaning the `Object` part can also be a `Map<String, Object>`, and so on...

The code snippet:

```
if(value instanceof Map) {
            try {
        return convert((Map<String, Object>)value);
        } catch (ClassCastException ccex) {
            ccex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

still has a warning on `(Map<String, Object>)value`:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Object>
```

While I can annotate it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, what I am curious about:

---

Is the `catch (ClassCastException ccex)` block above enough to avoid any issues with that unsafe cast?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the `catch (ClassCastException ccex)` block above enough to avoid any issues with that unsafe cast?

No, precisely *because* it's not checked. It will check that it's a `Map`, but that's all it is at the JVM level, due to *type erasure*. It could contain non-String keys, and that cast won't detect it.

Consider this example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Map raw = new HashMap();
       raw.put(new Object(), 10);

       // This cast won't fail
       Map<String, Object> typed = (Map<String, Object>) raw;

       // But this will fail...
       for (String key : typed.keySet()) {
           System.out.println(key);
       }
   }
}
```

Basically the compiler is inserting a cast on each access to keys or values, and those hidden casts can fail - but they're *not* at the same place as the cast to `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never get a `ClassCastException` for an unchecked cast because that's the definition of what an unchecked cast is.

You *will*, however, get that exception from within the `convert` method if it tries to downcast the map keys to `String`.

But in any case, these two issues are unrelated: Generics are about *compile-time* type safety only and `ClassCastException`s are about protecting type safety at runtime.

So, whether the catch-block is enough to avoid type issues in your case is not known. It *may* be enough, but there are certainly no general guarantees.

Comment: So, can I ditch the try/catch in that particular block? (the keys are treated in another place anyway).

Comment: As I said, it's all subject to what your code actually does. If you never refer to the keys as strings then you won't get the exception.